# Filter GitHub repos from the topics

Tags: repository, github-api

I want to filter and fetch the list of [Repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-organization-repositories) by the topic.

[image]

Let's say I need the repository list that has the topic `connector`.
But, unfortunately I couldn't find a way to do this.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to filter the repos by the topics.

https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-for-repositories